# if columns contain value then don't use random function in php

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have used random function in PHP as:

```
$SELECT * FROM add_question WHERE section_id = :section_id AND status = :status ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT {$row_random['total_question']}";
```

I have column named 'instruction' in my database table. It is not mandatory column.
but if it is present, same data is present in 3 to 5 rows(continue 3 to 5 rows).
so i need to make use of random function in this way:
If instruction column contains data, then fetch all the rows containing that same data in continuity not in random. AND if instruction column is empty then fetch random rows

for example:

```
ID  |  INSTRUCTION  |  QUESTION  | OPT1 | OPT2 | OPT 3
 1  |               |    q1      |    a |    b | c 
 2  |               |    q2      |    a |    b | c 
 3  |               |    q3      |    a |    b | c 
 4  |               |    q4      |    a |    b | c 
 5  |               |    q5      |    a |    b | c 
 6  | ins           |    q6      |    a |    b | c 
 7  | ins           |    q7      |    a |    b | c 
 8  | ins           |    q8      |    a |    b | c 
 9  |               |    q5      |    a |    b | c 
 10 |               |    q5      |    a |    b | c 
 11 |               |    q5      |    a |    b | c 
 12 |               |    q5      |    a |    b | c 
 13 |               |    q5      |    a |    b | c
```

if random function is used for 10 rows on above table it should return :
ids(1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13)
OR ids (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).
If Id '6' is returned then id 7,8 should also be returned with the total of 10 rows. ids with instructions should either returned all or NONE. If all are returned then they should be in continue order (not as 7, 8, 6) or etc.

Comment: You might want to add sample data here which demonstrates your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited my question.